# Not using dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

There is an abstract class BasePet and some child classes. I want to make a function

```
BasePet* foo(BasePet*);
```

which will make copies of objects from static memory to heap. Is there any way except using dynamic_cast? (For example, if there may be another child classes which are unknown for me and I want foo() to be usable for them all).

Comment: You can create a `clone` and override it for each class. I didn't vote you down. Someone else.

Comment: Are you free to modify `BasePet` and its derived classes, or do you need to do this from outside the class?

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify `BasePet` and its derived classes, the typical way is to create a `clone` method in `BasePet` and require that each derived class override it. Generally this looks like:

```
/*
This is what BasePet::clone() would look like if you wrote it, but normally that would be pure virtual.    

BasePet *BasePet::clone() const
{
    return new BasePet(*this);
}
*/

BasePet *Dog::clone() const
{
    return new Dog(*this);
}

BasePet *Cat::clone() const
{
    return new Cat(*this);
}

// ... and so on ...
```

If you don't have access to the class implementations, my first recommendation would be to try and figure out a way to do what you're trying to do without copying the objects, due to the concerns you raised about new derived classes appearing, as well as the implementations of the classes changing in ways that might affect what the code needs to do. If there's absolutely no way around it, you'll need to use some form of run-time type identification (RTTI); I would use `typeid` rather than `dynamic_cast` so that you can test for an exact match and don't get tripped up if the derived class `D` Is itself the base class for another derived class `D2` that you didn't know about.

Comment: whouldn't `BasePet::clone()` be pure `virtual`?

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, that's probably true. I had intended it to be interpreted as more of a general blueprint than an exact implementation, but I can see how that would be misleading, so I'll try and clean that up.